# Multiply inverse matrix with another one

Tags: matlab

I want to multiply two matrices, the first matrix is the inverse of A, and the second matrix is B,

```
 input('Enter The first Matrix')
 A = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 0 ]
 [m n] = size(A)
  if m==n 
      if det(A)==0
          disp('inverse does not exist')
      else 
          invv=inv(A)
          disp(invv)
      end 
  else 
      disp('Number of rows and columns are not equel , no inverse')
  end
  input('Enter The second Matrix')
  B = [ 1 ; 1 ; 1 ]
```

How can I verify that the number of columns in the first matrix is equal to the number of rows in the second matrix, so that they can be multiplied?

Comment: You are already familiar with the `size` function and comparison operator `==` as you have already used them in your code. What issue are you facing then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function [X] = dot_inv(X,x)
     % X   - numeric array
     % x   - cell array of numeric vectors
     % DIM - dimensions to omit (asumes ndims(X) = numel(x))
     % Y  - inner product obtained by summing the products of X and x along DIM
     % initialise dimensions
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [m n] = size(X)
     if m==n 
          if det(X)==0
             error('Error. \n inverse does not exist.')
          else 
             X=inv(X)
         end 
     else 
          error('Error. \n Number of rows and columns are not equel , no inverse!')
     end

     if iscell(x)
         DIM = (1:numel(x)) + ndims(X) - numel(x);
     else
         DIM = 1;
         x   = {x};
     end

     % inner product using recursive summation (and bsxfun)
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     for d = 1:numel(x)
         s         = ones(1,ndims(X));
         s(DIM(d)) = numel(x{d});
         X         = bsxfun(@times,X,reshape(full(x{d}),s));
         X         = sum(X,DIM(d));
     end

     % eliminate singleton dimensions
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     X = squeeze(X);

return
```